# If $\sup A\not\in A$ then $A$ contains a countably infinite subset

Tags: real-analysis, soft-question

I am required to show that if a bounded non empty set $A\subseteq \mathbf{R}$ is such that $\sup A\not\in A$, then $A$ contains a countably infinites subset.

Now my idea is that for each $k\in\mathbf{N}$ there would exist $a_k\in A$ such that $\sup A-\frac{1}{k}<a_k$ with the required set being $H = \{a_1,a_2,\dots\}$ but how can i modify this construction to ensure that all elements of $H$ are distinct?

Comment: Why do you want the elements to be distinct?

Comment: Simply throw out all of the ones that coincide. If there were finitely many such, then since your sequence converges, it must be eventually constant (if there are infinitely many of two different values, then it has a (constant) subsequence converging to each), but it converges to $\mathop{\mathrm{sup}}A$, so this would mean that $\mathop{\mathrm{Sup}}A \in A$, so we must have infinitely many distinct $a_n$.

Answer (score 2):

Try this: if a set $A\subset\Bbb R$ is finite and nonempty then $\sup A\in A$.